# VOTACIÓN QUE REGISTRE UN SOLO VOTO POR USUARIO O VOTANTE CON PHP Y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, php7

Estoy retomando la pregunta ya q me lo sugieren tengo la siguiente bd... yo logro que se realicen los voto con una consulta de actualización que inicia el campo voto en cero (0)
         $voto = $voto + 1;

```
        $consulta2 = " UPDATE resultados SET voto = $voto WHERE id_res = '$id_asp' ";

            $result2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta2);   

        header("Location:index.php");
```

lo que no logro es q cada persona q accede al sistema con **usuario y contraseña** pueda votar solo una vez.... lo intento agregando la tabla **login_aspirante** con los campos (id_login, id_aspirante) pero no logro insertar nada en esta tabla y por ende no puede detener a la persona q voto para q no lo siga haciendo...
Será q me pueden ayudar a solucionar este proceso....
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ponle una restricción `UNIQUE` en la tabla y así no permitirá que haya más de un voto por cada persona.

Comment: @A.Cedano hola de antemano muchas gracias por la respuesta pero la verdad no se como hacer pra que se pueda registrar un usuario y pueda limitar a q pueda votar una sola vez...

Comment: hola @A.Cedano sera que me pueder ayudar y decirme en que tabla se debe colocar esa restricción según las tablas de la base de datos que actualmente tengo y como lo hago

Answer (score 0):

Ok muchas gracias por su ayuda....
Aunque tuve muchas dificultades con el pc el internet y otros factores hasta hora lo solucione..Solo había agregue un campo estado en mi tabla login para saber si estaba en 1 no podia seguir y si estaba en 0 si podría pasar al form.
y esto lo hice con una consulta de actualización....